Chromium based MSEdge or Chrome Headless Printing Exit Code 21
I'm using MSEdge.exe in headless mode to convert some HTML Output from my C# app to PDF. The relevant bit of the code that I'm using is below:
string processExe = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe";
string processArgs = $"--headless --run-all-compositor-stages-before-draw --virtual-time-budget=6000 --no-pdf-header-footer --print-to-pdf-no-header --print-to-pdf=\"{outputFilePath}\" \"{inputFilePath}\"";
var printPDF = Process.Start(processExe, processArgs);
printPDF.WaitForExit();

This worked fine for the last year or so, until today! It seems that there's been an update to something in Edge, and now I'm getting "Exit Code 21" (and no PDF of course), which I cannot find any documentation for.
Does anyone have any idea?
Thanks

Getting reports of this rolling in now too. affecting multiple countries, different businesses/different Antivirus. Also just started/noticed today

https://issues.chromium.org/issues/361784547

The issue seems to be related to Chromium having merged the headless and non-headless into a single exe, and now headless exits when the gui-version is open. This change came to Microsoft Edge with version 128.0.2739.42.
The problem is exacerbated in Edge, because some copilot-integration seems to prevent Edge from closing its processes when you close the window.
A dirty workaround is to use:
--headless=old

This forces the headless mode to use the previous behavior with the standalone headless exe, which will work even though a Edge gui window is open or has been open.
However, it should be noted that this solution only works short-term, as this old headless mode will soon be removed. From the debug output, when using old headless mode:

Old Headless mode will be removed from the Chrome binary soon. Please use the new Headless mode (https://permanently-removed.invalid/docs/chromium/new-headless) or the chrome-headless-shell which is a standalone implementation of the old Headless mode (https://permanently-removed.invalid/blog/chrome-headless-shell).

^^ For some reason Microsoft thinks that linking to google documentation is evil. The working links should probably have been https://developer.chrome.com/docs/chromium/new-headless and https://developer.chrome.com/blog/chrome-headless-shell respectively.

MS Edge specifically still fails in  current Version Version 130.0.2849.80 (Official build)
Confirmed there has been some current regression, in Chromium's and Edge v128/9 & 130. To work for command line convert this page to PDF you may need to step back the print engine with --headless=old BUT for a permanent solution see the comments and script below.
Fails
With --headless=new or just --headless (defaults to new)
Reputedly ONLY if another session of edge is active in memory (very common)
However have just tested Version 129 with NO GUI or other session active, and still get a total fail (PARTIAL RESULT.pdf) starting with,

ERROR:edge_auth_errors.cc(523)] EDGE_IDENTITY: Get Default OS Account failed: Error: Primary Error: kImplicitSignInFailure, Secondary Error: kAccountProviderFetchError, Platform error: 0, Error string: Every renderer should have at least one task provided by a primary task provider. If a "Renderer" fallback task is shown, it is a bug. If you have repro steps, please file a new bug and tag it as a dependency of crbug.com/739782.

With a GUI version in memory there is no output same as before in 128.
msedge.lnk --headless --print-to-pdf="%cd%\test.pdf" "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78912977/msedge-headless-printing-exit-code-21"

Works (for now in version 128/9 and version 130 !) --headless=old
msedge.lnk --headless=old --print-to-pdf="%cd%\test.pdf" "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78912977/msedge-headless-printing-exit-code-21"

OR
chrome-headless-shell.exe --print-to-pdf=.....
451333 bytes written to file C:\............

Update
Bug reports over past few days
https://issues.chromium.org/issues/361784547 (Fix "in progress") classified as duplicate of 362545030

New headless cannot run in parallel with itself or regular Chrome on Windows


This is a known problem: new headless on Windows is unable to run in parallel with headful Chrome or another instance of new headless Chrome unless it's given a unique user data directory using the --user-data-dir switch.

NO does not make any difference in this case (still fails)
Cannot find any working solution such as try different combinations of --user-data-dir="c:\test" or --profile-directory="Default". whilst there are some good PDF results, they all have headless error conditions when not using =old.
https://issues.chromium.org/issues/361863270

Chrome dev protocol HeadlessExperimental.enable() is not available on headless=new

https://issues.chromium.org/issues/361963983

Shell-Scripts with --headless or --headless=new fail

https://issues.chromium.org/issues/362301064 (Fix "in progress")

Headless print-to-pdf is no longer functional unless headless=old
Duplicate https://issues.chromium.org/issues/365378963
Duplicate https://issues.chromium.org/issues/365405772
Duplicate https://issues.chromium.org/issues/364634016


also suggests use set --user-data-dir=C:\somewhere and ensure the appropriate app pool identity had permissions to that path.

NO does not make any difference in this case (still fails)
https://issues.chromium.org/issues/363916145

php exec chromium --headless=new doesn't work

Still a problem Today with Version 130.0.2849.80 (Official build)
Chromium teams suggestion is to short term use --headless=old but migrate your headless activities before that is removed.

To print loads of PDFs you would be better off using the old headless forcing it with --headless=old switch. Keep in mind that old headless will be removed from Chrome binary soon and this option will not be available anymore.

Instead, you will need to use the standalone version of old headless aka chrome headless shell, see details here: https://developer.chrome.com/blog/chrome-headless-shell

Headless modes:


The old Headless mode is a lightweight wrapper around Chromium's //content module, and it therefore has substantially fewer dependencies. Specifically, it does not require X11/Wayland, D-Bus, and is in some ways more performant than the fully-fledged Chrome browser. This makes it suitable for use cases such as automated screenshotting or web scraping.
New Headless on the other hand is the real Chrome browser, and is thus more authentic, reliable, and offers more features. This makes it more suitable for high-accuracy end-to-end web app testing or browser extension testing.
In other words, there's a trade-off between performance and authenticity. Which Headless mode is most fitting for you? It depends on your use case.

Answer
Use Headless Shell it is much faster and lighter (and simpler)
Here using current 32bit Windows from https://storage.googleapis.com/chrome-for-testing-public/128.0.6613.119/win32/chrome-headless-shell-win32.zip
Note at this time current version is 131.0.6778.69

Helper script to download and unpack latest stable version. You will need to adjust first 2 lines for 64bit (=chrome-headless-shell-win64.zip & =win64/%download%)
set "download=chrome-headless-shell-win32.zip"
set "variant=win32/%download%"

curl -o LATEST_RELEASE_STABLE.txt https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/LATEST_RELEASE_STABLE
set /p version=<LATEST_RELEASE_STABLE.txt
curl -O https://storage.googleapis.com/chrome-for-testing-public/%version%/%variant%
tar -xf %download%

Result will be an unpacked folder that can be overwritten as required by rerun the script.


Thanks! Powershell version:
`$download = "chrome-headless-shell-win32.zip"
$variant = "win32/$download"
Invoke-WebRequest -OutFile LATEST_RELEASE_STABLE.txt -Uri "https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/LATEST_RELEASE_STABLE"
$version = Get-Content -Path LATEST_RELEASE_STABLE.txt 
Invoke-WebRequest -OutFile $download -Uri "https://storage.googleapis.com/chrome-for-testing-public/$version/$variant"
Expand-Archive $download`


You know, I noticed that slowness too! Super weird. curl and tar were giving me issues so I used the PS meta functions, but it could probably be made to work with those. I was using this as part of a deployment helper script
